# How to replace Promise.defer with new Promise()

Tags: node.js, promise

So I see that `Promise.defer` is now deprecated and we are now supposed to use `new Promise` instead. I don't see how to do this however for this example?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var interval;

var rollDice = function (resolver) {
  console.log("rolling");
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) == 7) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    resolver.resolve();
  }
}

var rollTill7 = function (ms) {
    var resolver = Promise.defer();
    interval = setInterval(function(){rollDice(resolver);},ms);
    return resolver.promise;
}

rollTill7(100).then(function(){
    console.log("rolled a 7");
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, it is recommended to move away from the old defer model because you want the creator of a promise to be responsible for resolving or rejecting it - this just makes the control flow a ton easier to follow.  You don't want to pass on the responsibility for resolving or rejecting to some other code.

If outside code is involved in the decision to resolve or reject (such as your `rollDice()` function), then it can return info which is used to resolve or reject.  For example, in your code example, it can be done like this.

Note that the `rollDice()` function is now just a dice rolling function that tells you whether you rolled a specific number of not.  It is then used by the other function to determine control flow rather than putting control flow in the dice rolling function itself.

```
var rollDice = function() {
  console.log("rolling");
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

var rollTillNum = function(num, ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if (rollDice() === num) {
               resolve();
               clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, ms);
    });
}

rollTillNum(7, 100).then(function(){
    console.log("rolled a 7");
});
```

**Summary of Changes:**

1. Promise management is self-contained, not delegated to some other function (makes logic of the code easier to follow) which is one of the main reasons to use the new Promise constructor and not the deferred construct.
2. The `interval` variable is now contained to a local scope.
3. The `rollDice()` function is now generic so it can be used in other contexts.
4. `rollDice()` now returns a 1-based value, not a 0-based value (since that's how dice work).
5. Rather than hardwire `rollTill7()`, it's now `rollTillNum()` and you pass it the number you want it to achieve.

---

While the above solution is more general (using an external function to provide feedback on whether you should resolve or not), in this specific case, if you don't even need the `rollDice()` function to be externally usable, then it can just be subsumed entirely inside of the `rollTillNum()` function:

```
var rollTillNum = function(num, ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) === num) {
               resolve();
               clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, ms);
    });
}

rollTillNum(7, 100).then(function(){
    console.log("rolled a 7");
});
```

---

Here's the above code made into a working demo:

```js
document.getElementById("roll").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var start = Date.now();
    rollTillNum(7, 100).then(function(cnt) {
        var elapsed = ((Date.now() - start) / 1000).toFixed(1);
        log("It took " + elapsed + " seconds and " + cnt + " rolls to roll a 7");
    });
});

var rollDice = function() {
  console.log("rolling");
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

var rollTillNum = function(num, ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var cntr = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            ++cntr;
            if (rollDice() === num) {
               resolve(cntr);
               clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, ms);
    });
}

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<button id="roll">
Roll a 7
</button><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct equivalent using `new Promise(constructorFn)` would be to write `interval = setInterval(...)` inside `constructorFn` and to pass constructorFn's resolve argument to `rollDice()` instead of your original Deferred object.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var interval;

var rollDice = function (resolve) {
  console.log("rolling");
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) == 7) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    resolve();
  }
};

var rollTill7 = function (ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            rollDice(resolve);
        }, ms);
    });
};

rollTill7(100).then(function() {
    console.log("rolled a 7");
});
```

The solution becomes much neater if `interval` and `rollDice()` are also moved the into the promise's constructor. Not only are two members removed from the outer namespace but also the need to pass `resolve` is avoided - it becomes reachable by `rollDice()` due to closure.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var rollTill7 = function (ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var interval;
        var rollDice = function () {
          console.log("rolling");
          if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) == 7) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            resolve();
          }
        };
        interval = setInterval(rollDice, ms);
    });
};

rollTill7(100).then(function() {
    console.log("rolled a 7");
});
```

Going one tiny but arguably significant step further, you would probably choose to move `rollDice()` into the `setInterval` expression as an anonymous function. This would side-step an issue with the named function that it does more than just "roll a dice" - it also resolves.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer as I appreciate the improved scoping solution.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom - I would not argue that either of these solutions are ideal.  The first still delegates responsibility for resolving the promise to an external function which is simply not necessary and can really complicate the ability for someone to understand and follow the code, especially in a larger body of code.  The whole point of not using a deferred in the first place is to keep the resolving and rejecting responsibility local, not to pass it off somewhere else.  The second example is convenient, but it hides the `rollDice()` function so it can't be used elsewhere

Comment: @GroovyDotCom - While it might be OK in this specific example to hide the `rollDice()` function, the more general case is where that function is declared externally because it is used elsewhere (otherwise, it doesn't even need to be a function at all).  You can see one of the other answers here for much more general solutions.

Comment: @jfriend00, I agree with all that. To demonstrate the principles of "how to replace Promise.defer with new Promise()" , I decided to stick as closely as possible to the OP's original approach. In practice I would do much as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks Roamer. Tough call but with the edits, I think Jfriend now has the complete answer.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom, what you have selected is a free [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). In amongst it is an answer to your question!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var rollDice = function (resolve) {
  console.log("rolling");
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) == 7) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    resolve();
  }
}

var rollTill7 = function (ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            rollDice(resolve);
        }, ms);
    });
}
```

Comment: There's really no reason for the `rollDice()` function to have to know anything about a promise somewhere and thus there's really no reason to delegate the resolving of the promise outside of the promise constructor.  The job in life for `rollDice()` is to make a random roll.  The code in `rollTill7()` can use a return value from `rollDice()` and then `rollTill7()` can determine if the desired number has been achieved and whether the promise should be resolved or not.  Promises are simplest to understand if they are created and resolved in the same block of code.

Comment: @jfriend00, you are right. I just replace `defer` with `new Promise`. However, it is better practise for your suggestion...

Comment: So, the solutions are specific to this problem only. What if we use simple Promise with resolve and reject instead of Promise.deferred as below -


 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve() 
    reject()
}